# Android - AudioTrack produces only noise

Tags: android, audio, android-audiorecord

I am trying to record sound (using Android's AudioRecord), and simultaneously play the recorded sound (using Android's AudioTrack). I initialize the recorder and output track as follows:

```
int buffersize = 2*AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
AudioTrack output = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT), AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Now when I press the start button this method is called:

```
int buffersize = 5*AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        recorder.startRecording();
        output.play();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + 3000) { // Always record 3 seconds
            byte[] myBuffer = new byte[buffersize];
            recorder.read(myBuffer, 0, buffersize);
            output.write(myBuffer, 0, buffersize);
        }
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        output.stop();
        output.release();
        stopThread(); // void stopThread() {recordThread = null;}
    }
}
recordThread.start();
```

Now all I hear is noise, nothing like the music I am recording.
What am I doing wrong? Please help.
Thanks in advance,
Jeroen D.

EDIT:
I have found the problem, namely that the rate (8000) is way too low. I tried it with 44100 on a real phone (because the android emulator supports only 8000), and now the quality is fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you need to read the result from record.read. it is the actually read number of bytes, hence the actual number of bytes to write in output.

Comment: I compared int buffersize with myBuffer.length, but they are both always 3200. So I am using `output.write(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.length)` now, but I don´t hear any difference, still only noise.

Comment: yes, that's because you inialize it that way and [] are immutable. but that is totally not the point. recorder.read returns a number. that number is the number of bytes in the buffer that have actually been written. It is this number that you need to pass as length in output.write.

Comment: Allright, so I changed my code to the following: `int length = recorder.read(myBuffer, 0, buffersize); output.write(myBuffer, 0, length)`. Is that what you meaned? I tested it, but also length is always 3200, and the noise as output didn't change.